# Wordpress Variables encode for search form

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem! Using this code to the search form WP

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" id="searchform">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="search&amp;" />
        <select name="category_name">
        <?php
            $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
               echo '<option value="&post_type=product&product_cat=' . $ricerca . $term->slug .'">', $term->name, "</option>\n";
            } ?>
        </select>
    <button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

return URL:

```
?s=primo&category_name=%26post_type%3Dproduct%26product_cat%3Dtest
```

I want to return:

```
?s=primo&category_name=&post_type=product&product_cat=test
```

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Use URL `urlencode(your url);`

Comment: nada... my url not change with urlencode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change form like this,

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" id="searchform">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="search&amp;" />
<select name="product_cat">
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<option value="' . $ricerca . $term->slug .'">', $term->name, "</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="category_name" value="" >
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
<button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, pass all the name and value parameters in hidden format in the form which need to be passed in the URL of the browser.

Separate category_name  and product_cat as select and hidden input

```
<form method="get" action="http://localhost/" id="searchform">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="search&amp;" />
        <select name="category_name">
            <option>test</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="product_cat" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
        <button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

when form will be submitted all the input having name will be in the URL.

Make the select dynamic by your query `$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat' );`